# Parsing Python datetime from string with day-seconds

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format

I'm trying to parse the date and time from a bunch of filenames that have one of these formats:

- `prefix.YYYY-MM-DD.suffix`
- `prefix.YYYY-MM-DD_HH:MM:SS.sufix`
- `prefix.YYYY-MM-DD-SSSSS.sufix`

The datetime formats for these three are:

- `prefix.%Y-%m-%d.suffix`
- `prefix.%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.suffix`
- `prefix.%Y-%m-%d-%?????.suffix`

The first two are easy to parse with the datetime module but I'm having trouble figuring out how to parse the 5-digit seconds which range from 00000 to 82800 (86400 seconds per day).

If at all possible, I'd like to use the standard `datetime` module as this needs to be extremely portable.

My goal is to have a function that can ingest multiple datetime formats so I need to stay away from a one off parser if possible.

```
def myparser(filename, datetimeformat):
    # do some stuff - maybe as easy as 
    datetimeobject = datetime.strptime(filename, datetimeformat)
    return datetimeobject
```

Any thoughts on how best to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do your 5-digit seconds only go up to 82800? Was that a typo?

Comment: Not really a typo, but I wasn't exactly clear either.  There is one file per hour and the last one is at hour 23.  23hours*60minutes*60seconds=82800seconds.  In other applications they could range from 00000 to 86400.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure how you're going to be able to do this without a special-case parser for the 5-digit-second format, seeing as there simply isn't a format specification for "seconds per day".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for all of them you split off the date and parse that as a `datetime.datetime` then parse the time into a `datetime.timedetla` and add it to the first value you should get where you need to be.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Not as clean as I was hoping but it will work for now.